# How to modify Datetime index format (UTC) in Pandas?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, time-series

I have a df that looks like this:

```
2015-01-29 08:30:00-05:00  199425  199950  199375  199825                  
2015-01-29 08:45:00-05:00  199825  199850  199650  199800                 
2015-01-29 09:00:00-05:00  199825  199900  199450  199625
```

How can I remove the -05:00 so It looks like this?:

```
2015-01-29 08:30:00  199425  199950  199375  199825                  
2015-01-29 08:45:00  199825  199850  199650  199800                 
2015-01-29 09:00:00  199825  199900  199450  199625
```

Just to clarify, the time is fine, I don't need to do any transformation on that, the modification is just the format, (-05:00)

**Update:**

For further clarity. The -5:00 comes out of applying this procedure

```
eastern = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
df.index = df.index.tz_localize(pytz.utc).tz_convert(eastern)
```

Thanks

Comment: In what kind of output to you want to format it? Just in the console output, or in something else?

Comment: @joris just in the console output. Thanks

Comment: You can of course remove the timezone with `.tz_localize(None)`, but that changes the actual values. Further, I don't know a way to change the way dates are formatted in the output

Comment: Try this! it 'dateStr = str(df)
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateStr.split(" ")[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
retDate = dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')'

Comment: @Java.beginner are you sure about datetime.datetime ?

Comment: Yes @hernanavella, I am sure and it works fine good for me...

Comment: @joris: `.tz_localize(None)` should preserve the local time as is. You might be confusing it with `.tz_convert(None)` that does convert to UTC first.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian No, I am not confusing it :-) That is why I recommended `tz_localize`, as this indeed keeps it in 'local' time. But you are removing the timezone, so you *are* changing the actual 'value'. But it depends on your application if this is OK or not.

Comment: [OP needs it only for display](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28238294/how-to-modify-datetime-index-format-utc-in-pandas?noredirect=1#comment44840148_28238294) therefore it is ok to remove the timezone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old question from Jan 2015.  But since there is no answer yet (although lots of comments), here is an answer in Oct 2019.  The original questioner probably found an answer already but just as a reference for the future.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

```py
import pandas as pd

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date_original': ['2015-01-29 08:30:00-05:00', '2015-01-29 08:45:00-05:00', '2015-01-29 09:00:00-05:00'],
    'measurement': [199425, 199825, 199825]
})

# make sure to convert date column to datetime, not string
df['date_original'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_original'])

print('Original dataframe:')
print(df)
print()

# remove the suffix from the date
df['date_transform'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_original']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print('Transformed dataframe:')
print(df)
print()
df
```