# in Pandas, how to get rid of (-00:00) in a DateTime index after it's converted using pytz.localize??

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, time-series, dataframe

Expanding a bit more on [a question I posted before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28238294/how-to-modify-datetime-index-format-utc-in-pandas).  I want to know how to format a datetime index in pandas after it has been transformed from UTC to eastern time.

So the procedure used to transform the index is:

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
df.index = df['DateTime']
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['DateTime'])
eastern = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
df.index = df.index.tz_localize(pytz.utc).tz_convert(eastern)
```

Now, this procedure works exactly as I want, except that it adds a (-05:00), to the index. So the index looks like this:

```
2015-01-29 08:30:00-05:00  199425  199950  199375  199825                  
2015-01-29 08:45:00-05:00  199825  199850  199650  199800                 
2015-01-29 09:00:00-05:00  199825  199900  199450  199625
```

What I want to do is to keep the date time as it is (after the transformation), but get rid of the (-05:00), so my dataframe looks like this:

```
2015-01-29 08:30:00  199425  199950  199375  199825                  
2015-01-29 08:45:00  199825  199850  199650  199800                 
2015-01-29 09:00:00  199825  199900  199450  199625
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please, specify how exactl, this question is different from the previous one. In particular, have you seen `.tz_localize(None)` in the comments?

Comment: I thought the procedure is more clear here. Localize (None) doesn't work because it doesn't convert. It defeats the purpose.

Comment: `.tz_localize(None)` gets rid of `'-05:00`` without changing the date itself as you've asked. If it "doesn't work" for you then you should update your question to mention how exactly does it fail in your case, at the very least show the invalid result that you get (ideally, you should [create minimal code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Anyway, it still says nothing about how this quesiton is different from the previous one.